# How to compute the lap count of a car

Tags: python

I want to compute the lap count of a car, means how many times a car has completed a lap. I have coordinates of the car attached as a csv file [csv file having car coordinates](https://drive.google.com/file/d/130Va_V7y57LuG1ao_sTOkZWfjqs4qRZn/view?usp=sharing)and size of the scene is height = 0.33 width = 0.342. I take the starting point as a first row of the csv file attached. The coordinates looks like this:
[Car moving coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Eyae.png)
Now I want to compute how many laps the car has taken, my logic to compute the laps is given below, it is that if the car has reached its starting point after crossing the vertical line than make it a one count of lap, [Laps coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH8t8.png) now the thing is that this game has different level in the first level car start from one starting point and go in anticlockwise direction and in the next level it has another starting point and it goes in clockwise direction. I am attaching my logic in python, in this data the lap count should be 11 but my function is giving me the count of 19. What should be done to avoid false lap count.

```
def count_laps(df, width, height, starting_y, tolerance_y=0.01):
    """
    Count the number of laps completed by a car based on its coordinates, without assuming a specific direction.
    
    Args:
        df (DataFrame): DataFrame containing the car's coordinates with columns 'XCoordinate' and 'YCoordinate'.
        width (float): Width of the track.
        height (float): Height of the track.
        starting_x (float): X-coordinate of the starting point.
        tolerance_y (float): Tolerance value for starting point's Y-coordinate. Default is 0.01.
    
    Returns:
        int: Number of laps completed by the car.
    """
    center_x = width / 2
    center_y = height / 2
    lap_count = 0
    crossed_ref = False
    prev_y = None
    starting_x = result.iloc[0]['XCoordinate']
    starting_y = result.iloc[0]['YCoordinate']  # Starting y-coordinate of the horizontal line
    tolerance_y = 0.001  # Tolerance for determining if a point is near the starting point
    prev_y = result.iloc[0]['YCoordinate']  # Initialize previous y-coordinate to None
    crossed_ref = False  # Initialize crossed_ref to False
    lap_count = 0  # Initialize lap count to 0

    for i in range(len(result)):
        x = result.iloc[i]['XCoordinate']
        y = result.iloc[i]['YCoordinate']

        # Check if the car has crossed the horizontal line and completed a lap
        if not crossed_ref and prev_y is not None and ((y <= (starting_y + tolerance_y) and y > starting_y and prev_y <= starting_y) or
                                                   (y >= (starting_y - tolerance_y) and y < starting_y and prev_y >= starting_y)):
            crossed_ref = True

        # Check if the car has crossed the reference position and is near the starting point
        if crossed_ref and prev_y is not None and ((y > (starting_y - tolerance_y) and prev_y <= starting_y and y > starting_y) or
                                                  (y < (starting_y + tolerance_y) and prev_y >= starting_y and y < starting_y)):
            crossed_ref = False
            lap_count += 1
            #print("Point crossed the reference position and is near the starting point:")
            print("x:", x, "y:", y)
            points.append((x,y))
        prev_y = y
    return lap_count

points=[]
#starting_x = 0.1912601
#starting_y = 0.0777104
starting_y =  result['YCoordinate'].iloc[0] #result is the data from csv file
width = 0.342
height = 0.33
lap_count = count_laps(result, width, height, starting_y, tolerance_y=0.01)
print("Lap Count: ", lap_count)
```

What is wrong in my logic or there is some problem with the data? how to avoid false count this function is giving.

Comment: I plotted the movement of the car on a per-lap basis, and it shows three things ([link](https://i.imgur.com/01wyyjU.png)) 1) Since a lap is defined as moving over a line along a Y coordinate, often the car crosses that line twice, once going down, and once going up. 2) Since the line for the lap is defined using the start point, sometimes the car doesn't trigger the lap because it doesn't go down far enough. 3) Sometimes the car teleports to the other side of the track, with a 14-16 second gap in observations.

Comment: I think a better algorithm to find the lap count might be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4840810/530160). Essentially, you pick a point in the center of your track, and track the change in angle in each step. At the end, it adds up how much change in angle has occurred.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your answer, the 14-16 gap is due to level change, like when the level changes the start and direction of the car changes, also if I make a check that change the starting point after 14 seconds or gap greater than 10 sec, will it make any difference to the logic?
how can I use it to get the total count by using the algorithm u mentioned?

Comment: Ok I understood how to count the laps, do you have any example of the algo you mentioned?

Comment: I have made a function of the algo you told and it is giving me count of 1072.